# Check if Integer is too great

Tags: java, integer, max, stack-overflow

I am working on an exchange system and the user is setting the price and amount for an exchange.

I want to make sure that the exchange is no greater than the Integer maximum value, but I am running into a problem.

When the amount of the exchange is put to 9 or more, even though I have a check to make sure the number is no greater than the maximum value, it does not work. I have done some debugging and when setting the amount to 9 while the price is 2,147,483,646 (1 less than the max number), it prints out this:

2,147,483,630 - 9

This is my debugging code, what should I add to it to make sure that this does not happen?

```
public void setPrimaryAmount(int primaryAmount) {
        int price = primaryAmount * this.price;
        System.out.println(Misc.format(this.price * primaryAmount) + " - " + primaryAmount);
        if (price > Integer.MAX_VALUE ||
                price == Integer.MAX_VALUE ||
                price >= Integer.MAX_VALUE ||
                price < 0 || price <= 0 ||
                price++ == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("Attempted to set a bad amount.");
            return;
        }
        this.primaryAmount = primaryAmount;
    }
```

"Attempted to set a bad amount" prints out until you enter an amount >= 9.

Comment: You do realize, I hope, that tests like `price < 0 || price <= 0` are redundant: `price <= 0` is entirely sufficient. Likewise for `price > Integer.MAX_VALUE || price == Integer.MAX_VALUE || price >= Integer.MAX_VALUE`, except there's the added wrinkle that an integer variable can **never** be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so `price == Integer.MAX_VALUE` is all you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't store a value in an int, and *then* check to see whether it's too big for an int. Store it in a long instead.

```
long price = (long)primaryAmount * (long)this.price;
```

Comment: Note that switching to longs for good ensures you can sell a planet without overflow.

Comment: @Tyluur We accept as answer (select the tick) when we're happy an answer resolves our concern.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, one approach would be to use

```
Math.addExact(int, int);
```

which according to Javadocs will throw an `ArithmeticException` if the result overflows an int. In other versions, I would recommend what Flight Odyssey suggested and use longs at least for these types of checks.

Answer (score 0):

When setting 'price' to `primaryAmount * this.price` to check if it is above Integer.MAX_VALUE or below Integer.MIN_VALUE, because **it is an integer** it will roll, for example, a value of Integer.MAX_VALUE += 1 will become Integer.MIN_VALUE and vice-versa therefore checking is not not needed. You could of course make it a bigger data type and then check but there is a faster way.
As long as we know what `this.price` is we can determine what the maximum value 'primaryAmount' can be without exeeding 2,147,483,646 once multiplied with `this.price` simply by doing it backwards:

```
int max = 2147483646 / this.price
```

This value could act as a max for a simple trim function to ensure it is within range, e.g:

```
private int confirmRange(int number, int max, int min) {
    if (number > max) number = max;
    if (number < min) number = min;
    return number;
}
```